# How to configure width and heigth from EditorJS?

Tags: editorjs

I have implemented EditorJS in a website, and everything is working.
The problem is that I don't know how to configure the Editor JS to reduce his width and height, and how to appear aligned on the left.

This is my code to instantiate EditorJS:

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="editorjs" name="detailed_draft"></div>
```

```
//javascript
const TOOLS = {
    list: {
        class: List,
        inlineToolbar: true
    },
    header: {
        class: Header,
        inlineToolbar: true 
    },
    underline: {
        class: Underline
    }
}

const editor = new EditorJS({
    /** 
     * Id of Element that should contain the Editor 
     */
    holder: 'editorjs',
    tools: TOOLS,
    placeholder: 'Write some Details!',
    data: obj
})
```

[image showing the EditorJS display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbJGv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on [this discussion](https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/discussions/1867) the solution is to override the EditorJS CSS.

```
<style>
    .ce-block__content,
    .ce-toolbar__content {
        max-width: unset;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. for any js framework, just add the css in the global scss file.